# rospy Subscriber object not getting destroyed?

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This just came up in an assignment that I'm grading, and I can't figure out why it works.  In the constructor of a class, there is:

`self.sub = rospy.Subscriber('/odom', Odometry, self.seek_goal)`

followed immediately by

`self.sub = rospy.Subscriber('/base_scan', LaserScan, self.laser_agg)`

My understanding is that, when `self.sub` is reassigned, the original `Subscriber` should go out of scope, get destroyed, and get garbage-collected.  However, **both** callbacks seem to run happily for the duration of the node's existence.

Any Python gurus out there with any insight?  I could guess about the object not getting reaped, but it should still go out of scope (and get destroyed), right?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48503/rospy-subscriber-object-not-getting-destroyed?/) by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1263 on 2012-11-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After looking at rospy's source code, it looks like no `__del__` method is implemented for subscribers. That means, topics are just not cleaned up when a subscriber object is destroyed. The user needs to manually unregister topics.

I'm not sure if this was intended behavior but I would consider filing an enhancement ticket.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-11-24**:
I recently noticed a similar issue with rospy service advertisements.